# ClassNotFoundException thrown by RootTools in JavaCommandCapture

Tags: java, android, eclipse, roottools

I followed the directions on the RootTools [usage](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki/Usage) and [run Java as root](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki/Java-as-root) wiki pages, but when I load my app with the following in onCreate() I get a ClassNotFoundException: com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass:

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;
import com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass;
import com.stericson.RootTools.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.CommandCapture;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.JavaCommandCapture;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.Shell;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RootTools.debugMode = true; //ON
    RootTools.log("roottools is logging");
    RootTools.handlerEnabled = false;

    Shell shell;
    try {
        shell = RootTools.getShell(true);
        JavaCommandCapture cmd = new JavaCommandCapture(
                43,
                false,
                this,
                "com.mycompany.TestActivity.RootToolsTest") {

            @Override
            public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                super.commandOutput(id, line);

            }
        };
        shell.add(cmd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
@RootClass.Candidate
private class RootToolsTest{
    public RootToolsTest(){
        Log.d("RootToolsTest", "testing a Java class run as root");
    }
}
```

The same thing happened when I tried RootTools' test class com.stericson.RootToolsTests.NativeJavaClass.  I've tried a number of configurations for the placement and inclusion of the RootTools.jar file (most notably ensuring that the RootTools jar is checked for export and moved to the top of the order and export list in Eclipse) but the ClassNotFoundException persists. The exact logcat output follows:

```
06-02 07:27:45.529: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): roottools is logging
06-02 07:27:45.529: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): Starting Root Shell!
06-02 07:27:45.539: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): Starting shell: su
06-02 07:27:46.409: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): CommandHandler not created
06-02 07:27:46.429: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): Executing: dalvikvm -cp /data/data
/com.hdradio.fmdelverrooted/files/anbuild.dex com.android.internal.util.WithFramework 
com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass 
com.hdradio.fmdelver.core.DelverActivity.RootToolsTest
06-02 07:27:46.749: D/Command(5165): ID: 43, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass
06-02 07:27:46.759: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-02 07:27:46.759: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
06-02 07:27:46.759: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at 
com.android.internal.util.WithFramework.main(WithFramework.java:36)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/stericson/RootTools/containers/RootClass
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,    ... 5 more
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43, Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at 
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,    at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-02 07:27:46.769: D/Command(5165): ID: 43,    ... 5 more
06-02 07:27:46.979: D/RootTools v3.4(5165): Command 43 finished.
```

My .classpath looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Users/myhome/devel_resources
/code/RootTools/RootTools-3.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" 
path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" 
path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

My development system configuration is as follows:
OS: Mac OS X 10.9.2
Eclipse: Kepler
ADT: 22.3
RootTools Version: 3.4

and my target platform:
Android: 4.1.1
Model: Sony Xperia E C1504 (rooted using SRSRoot and the 'Gandalf' exploit)
Firmware: Stock Kernel Xperia E C1505_11.3.A.0.47 (supposed to work for C1504 as well)

Any ideas why Android can't find the com.stericson.RootTools.containers.RootClass class?

Comment: I know this is a year old but you most likely did not copy your dex file to your app's files directory.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, the jar file was currupted and the .class file was physically absent. Exactly what the exception is telling you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, add more details (how you found it, how you corrected it), even if it sounds obvious. Please add more information if you don't want your answered be removed.

Comment: as far as I can tell the RootClass.class file exists in the jar.  I re-downloaded and re-configured my project anyway to check and the result was the same (ClassNotFoundException)